# How to hide data, but keep it in tooltip in c3.js

Tags: javascript, c3.js

The title says it all. I have a set of data that I want to show in the tooltip, but I don't want to show in the actual bar graph. I tried including the data, and then using `hide: ['dataToHide']`, and then following up with

```
tooltip: {
   show: 'dataToHide'
}
```

but I just can't manage to get it working. I know I can format the tooltip, but whenever I insert anything myself, the formatting of the tooltip seems to become blank. In addition, I'm not sure how to add another option to the tooltip itself.

Comment: Do you mean you want to have tooltips also where you don't have a "point" (meaning a data entry)? Or you just want tooltips to tell more then axes labels where you have entries?

Comment: I have a set of data who's data points I only want to be visible in the tool tip whenever you hover of the other data. I don't want the set of data's data points to actually be in the graph itself.

Comment: So you want to just see the "line" without points and labels, and see values just when hovering them, did I get it right?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.

Comment: You should then search how to remove axis ticks. [Here](http://c3js.org/examples.html) at `#Axis` there are a lot of examples for manipulating ticks. Maybe you would like to take a look at [X Axis Tick Count](http://c3js.org/samples/axes_x_tick_count.html) and maybe try to set its number to zero not to have ticks showing up.

Comment: I have the same question as you. I came across [this](https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/731), which allowed me to keep the hidden data in the c3 structure, but I can't find a way of accessing the hidden columns in the tooltip callback...

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this question ever got answered, but what I ended up doing was just taking the `name` of the data you want to hide on the graph but keep in the tooltip and then in the CSS doing this.

So let's say you have the data like this:

`columns: {
   ['showthis', ...],
   ['hidethis', ...]
}`

`.c3-target-hidethis {
    display: none;
}`

This will keep the lines hidden in the graph (or the bar) while also keeping the data in the tooltip. :) I hope this helps!